# Whats the use of argument (FragmentManager fm) and Bundle args = new Bundle();?

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, android-tabs

an Android newbie here trying to learn Swipe Views with Tabs from Android developer website. But I can't figure out what's the use of certain code used here as I am trying to understand each part of the code, Please help.

[Creating Swipe Views with Tabs](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#tabs)

```
// Since this is an object collection, use a FragmentStatePagerAdapter,
// and NOT a FragmentPagerAdapter.
public class DemoCollectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public DemoCollectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment = new DemoObjectFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        // Our object is just an integer :-P
        args.putInt(DemoObjectFragment.ARG_OBJECT, i + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 100;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "OBJECT " + (position + 1);
    }
}
```

I can't understand the purpose of the argument **FragmentManager fm** and **super(fm)** in the class' constructor.

Also, can't under the use of this code

```
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    // Our object is just an integer :-P
    args.putInt(DemoObjectFragment.ARG_OBJECT, i + 1);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
```

Please help me to understand tabs activity or provide me a good source to understand this and other android concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are required to have empty constructors.  Because of this, they can't have arguments passed in to them like you normally would for an object.  So the (rather cumbersome and painful) way they got around this is with the `get/setArguments()` method.  Typically, you would do something like this with a Framgnent:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

   public static MyFragment newInstance(int parameter1, String parameter2) {
      Bundle args = new Bundle();
      args.putInt("parameter1", parameter1);
      args.putString("parameter2", parameter2);

      MyFragment newFragment = new MyFragment();
      newFragment.setArguments(args);
      return newFragment;
   }

   private int parameter1;
   private String parameter2;

   @Overide
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        parameter1 = args.getInt("parameter1");
        parameter2 = args.getString("parameter2");
   }
}
```

Then, when you want to create a Fragment, rather than instantiating one by creating a new object, you call `MyFragment frag = MyFragment.newInstance(1, "parameter");`.  This helps ensure that your `MyFragment` is in a proper state.

The example you're pulling from chose not to use this technique, but in reality it's a real pain to remember which parameters are *required* when creating the fragment.  The `newInstance` method helps tell you what it needs in order to run properly.

EDIT:

The reason this:

```
public DemoCollectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
   super(fm);
}
```

Is you are extending `FragmentPagerAdapter`.  This adapter does a lot of fragment adding and removal for you and for this is required a `FragmentManager`.  In Java, if a class doesn't have an empty default constructor, all child classes must create a constructor that calls the `super()` constructor to full construct the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

```
//the constructor of your adapter - the fragment manager is needed to    
//inflate the fragment when you swipe to another tab
public DemoCollectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    //with super you are calling the constructor of the base class
    //you are extending your class from (FragmentStatePageAdapter)
    //and pass the fragmentmanager to the super constructor
    super(fm);
}


//this method returns the fragment for a certain position
//it is needed to tell the adapter which fragment to return
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    //you are creating the fragment and passing the needed
    //parameters here
    //you could do it like this but I would create a static
    //method newInstance(...) in the fragment and use this
    //you can read more about this and the reason for it here: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/using-newinstance-to-instantiate.html
    Fragment fragment = new DemoObjectFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    // Our object is just an integer :-P
    args.putInt(DemoObjectFragment.ARG_OBJECT, i + 1);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}


//needed to tell the adapter how many fragment it contains
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 100;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return "OBJECT " + (position + 1);
}
```

}